# How to make PDO simpler

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

While I converted myself (finally!) from mysql_connect() to PDO::etc and all the other mysql functions, to adopt a better, DB abstraction coding style to my websites, I couldn't help noting how object oriented, error exception handling and prepared statements based this stuff is. I'm OK with all this, but I'm sure the beginner next to me only gets as far as the simplicity of copy-and-paste.

Are there any libraries/scripts/user contributions to make the DBO calls simpler, such as removing exception handling and object orientate, or at least n00b friendly?

I have made my own library with PDO, but I'm not sure what there is already out there?

Comment: Removing exception handling? IMHO, that's one of the good parts :)

Comment: So essentially you're asking how to make life easier for the dev next to you who can't be bothered to learn how things work? Well, I'm afraid you can't. There is no helping people like that, and you should not waste your time enabling this behaviour pattern. Either he learns how things work or he falls behind and eventually loses his job. It's his problem, not yours.

Comment: The [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension offers a procedural (non-object-oriented) style, for those who want it.

Comment: Have you considered mentoring your n00b co-worker in order to pass on your expertise?  Its obvious that you have already identified the problem .. now come through with a solution that addresses the root cause.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Such an unnecessary comment. He is obviously trying to learn by asking that question. He just have a hard time understanding the syntax and meaning of PDO.

Comment: @cubsink No he isn't, he's saying he's learned it (good) but a colleague hasn't (bad) so he wants to make easier for his colleague, which is failing to address the root cause of the problem. Although I accept the comment may have been a little more snarky than necessary and for that I apologise. I see you've suggested the use of frameworks with ORM - which is not a bad suggestion, but it also fails to address the real problem. I don't believe anyone should use a framework until they understand how it would work without one, as soon as you need to do something the framework can't you're stuck.

Comment: @DaveRandom: hehe totally missed that it was his friend. Missed the whole context of this question. I guess I'm kinda tired..

Comment: Well I think @DaveRandom is actually correct, I wouldn't be at this stage if, in the past, some senior developer didn't continuously told me 'Go google it and let me know' lol.
I do think to though, that you can't teach someone error handling AND database connections AND sql AND error objects AND object oriented syntax for DBs in, let's say, one month. Also, most companies hire junior web developers and place them wit existing code that may use the proper way PHP, PDO etc. Can you expect from them to understand this from time zero? Throw them something easier first imho...

Comment: I hate to be considered a junior dev just because I'm young. I've met senior developer with less skills. I'll stop ranting now but as a junior dev you should know about SQL, OO syntax and all that you mentioned. Of course, we developers are often not to blame who they hire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a framework that uses an ORM, like Laravel: http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent

But then you are not writing your own SQL-queries (or its not recommended), else you can just use MySQLi: https://www.php.net/mysqli_query but neither of them removes any objective view I think. But both may be easier to understand for a new programmer.

I recommend you to go for a framework on at least your future projects.

Here is some examples of them all:

- http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent (Laravel)
- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html (CodeIgniter)
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html (CakePHP)
- http://li3.me/docs/manual/quickstart (Lithium, for alternative database MongoDB)

Comment: You should also try Doctrine2 (http://www.doctrine-project.org/). It's another ORM framework (like Laravel), not hard to use, and is actually very complete.